# C# Get file size of array with paths

Tags: c#, arrays, file, filesize

I am new to arrays and I want to display the size (in MB) of multiple files into a textBox. The paths to the files are in an array.

```
var Files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I saw this code in another post to get the size of a file:

```
long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(file).Length;
```

How can I add all of the file sizes to an int/string and write them into the textBox?

Comment: MB is just `FileInfoLength / (1024*1024)`

Comment: @loyd, does the below answers solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, just use *Linq* [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var results = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Select(file => new FileInfo(file).Length);

 TextBox1.Text = string.Join(", ", results);
```

if you want to sum them, just use [`Enumerable.Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 TextBox1.Text = $"{results.Sum():N3}";
```

**Update**

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public enum SizeUnits
    {
        Byte, KB, MB, GB, TB, PB, EB, ZB, YB
    }

    public static string ToSize(this Int64 value, SizeUnits unit)
    {
        return (value / (double)Math.Pow(1024, (Int64)unit)).ToString("0.00");
    }
}

 TextBox1.Text = results.Sum().ToSize();
```

Comment: One more question, is there a way to get a decimal value? In my case a file has the size of 14.9 MB but I end up with 14 MB.

Comment: @loyd you can read more about them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: I used $"{results.Sum() / (1024*1024):N3}"; to get the file size in MB but the decimal value gets filled with zeros only. What is my mistake?

Comment: @loyd you could use $"{results.Sum() / (double)(1024*1024):N3}", or i updated my answer if you want to get fancy

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add complexity by using LINQ and want to practice with arrays:

```
var Files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

long length = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
{
    length += new FileInfo(Files[i]).Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code may work to you.

```
var FilesAndSizes = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string,int>(item, new System.IO.FileInfo(item).Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` you're able to calculate the total size while only traversing the array once.

To get the total size for all files of an extension:

```
long totalSizeInBytes = 0;
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path, "*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{                
    totalSizeInBytes += new FileInfo(file).Length;
}
```

To get a list of all file sizes:

```
var results = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path, "*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Select(file => new FileInfo(file).Length);

TextBox1.Text = string.Join(", ", results);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that DirectoryInfo object cuold be smarter for your case istead of Directory object.

Look at that example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string filetype = ".jpg";

    // Make a reference to a directory.
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
    // Get a reference to each file in that directory.
    FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles("*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    // Display the names and sizes of the files.
    Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files:", di.Name);
    foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
        Console.WriteLine("The size of {0} is {1} bytes.", f.Name, f.Length);
}
```

the GetFiles method returns an array of FileInfo objects, where you can find the filesize.

Parameters:

I this example i'm writing to console output but in the same way you can add the text to your textbox.

```
   mytexbox.Text += String.Format("The size of {0} is {1} bytes.\r\n", f.Name, f.Length);
```